# Error install sbt

Tags: sbt

I tried to install sbt on high sierra,

I have installed the build tool using : "brew install sbt" , after that i tried to run the sbt on "./.brew/Cellar/sbt/1.1.0/bin/sbt

i got that error.

```
java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1115)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:88)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: Operation not supported

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. All we see is that a JVM has raised an IOException. Assume no one here knows what SBT or "high sierra" is.

Comment: I have installed the build tool using : "brew install sbt" , after that i tried to run the sbt on "./.brew/Cellar/sbt/1.1.0/bin/sbt"

Comment: This should be in the question, not a comment. Comments can be removed. Questions should be stand-alone. It sounds like you need to circle back with brew or whoever maintains sbt for brew.

Comment: At any rate, this isn't a great fit for SO, which is more about coding, not necessarily installing and running tools for very specific environments.

Comment: I don't think you followed the instructions here properly: https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Mac.html Work through that (and pay attention to the details) and work through the steps for proving it works.

Comment: I think, i've followed all the steps, i installed it using brew, and also through the zip package, but got the same error

Comment: Then it looks like there is something wrong with your brew install, your system, or the brew package. Best to raise this with the package maintainer. My guess is that this is a permissions issue.

Comment: My program is i tried to install it on NFS

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need *homebrew* to install SBT.  Download it directly at https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html, then extract and drop it into your home directory.

With Terminal, update permissions:

```
chmod -R 700 sbt/bin/sb
```

Open the Bash Profile.

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

export PATH=/Users/username/sbt/bin:$PATH

*Username* is your user name.  For example, export PATH=/Users/john/sbt/bin:$PATH

To test, close and re-open Terminal.  Run:

```
sbt --version
```

I wrote step-by-step instructions on [my blog](https://code.linedrop.io/articles/Installing-Simple-Build-Tool) earlier.